# How to change GECOS field on HMC?

Tags: ibm-hmc

How can we change the GECOS field for a user if we have hmcsuperadmin rights?

Comment: This may also be dependent on HMC version; maybe include that as part of the question and answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
chhmcusr -i "name=foobaruser,description=PROOOBA"
```

"PROOOBA" is the new GECOS field 
"foobaruser" is the username

Answer (score 0):

Via the commandline: chhmcusr -u your-username-here -t desc -v "your new GECOS here"

Via the GUI (exact wording may vary depending on HMC version): HMC Management - Manage User Profiles and Access - Select the user - Modify/View